# Error al convertir fechas en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy usando el siguiente código

```js
  for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        var date = new Date(''+i+'/03/2021 13:00:00');
        var format = Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-PT').format(date);
        console.log(format);
    }
```

Pero no es como esperaba, el mes terminó en lugar del día y el día terminó en lugar del mes analizando. Esperaba el siguiente resultado:

```
01/03/2021 13:00
02/03/2021 13:00
03/03/2021 13:00
04/03/2021 13:00
05/03/2021 13:00
06/03/2021 13:00
07/03/2021 13:00
08/03/2021 13:00
09/03/2021 13:00
10/03/2021 13:00
11/03/2021 13:00
12/03/2021 13:00
13/03/2021 13:00
14/03/2021 13:00
15/03/2021 13:00
16/03/2021 13:00
17/03/2021 13:00
18/03/2021 13:00
19/03/2021 13:00
20/03/2021 13:00
21/03/2021 13:00
22/03/2021 13:00
23/03/2021 13:00
24/03/2021 13:00
25/03/2021 13:00
26/03/2021 13:00
27/03/2021 13:00
28/03/2021 13:00
29/03/2021 13:00
30/03/2021 13:00
31/03/2021 13:00
```

Necesito que esté en este formato (dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm)

¿Cómo puedo resolver el código anterior para que sea correcto y esté formateado sin errores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si estás buscando una forma más compleja de hacerlo, pero podrías simplemente invertir el lugar del `'+i+'` y el `'03/'` y así obtienes el resultado que estás buscando.

Para que muestre también la hora, se le puede pasar como segundo argumento a la función `DateTimeFormat()` el siguiente objeto: `{dateStyle:'medium', timeStyle: 'medium'}`.

Así con `dateStyle:'medium'` se le da formato a la fecha y con `timeStyle: 'medium'` a la hora.

Aquí en esta documentación encontrarás más opciones:

[Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
  var date = new Date('03/'+i+'/2021 13:00:00');
  var format = Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-PT', { dateStyle:'medium', timeStyle: 'medium' }).format(date);
  console.log(format);
}
```

Comment: gracias excelente, no sabía que era eso =)

Comment: Genial. Igual recién acabo de notar que también querías que se mostrara la hora. Ahora edito mi respuesta para agregarle eso también.